# Apache Won't Display PHP File In Website Directory

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm building a webpage which has a page allowing users to log in, called `login.php`. This page is located in the same root directory as my `index.html` page. When I open up `index.html` and go to click on the login link, I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/websites/testsite.com/www/login.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I have no idea why this isn't working because my index page (and every other page that I have made thus far) links to that same `login.php` page, which exists in the same directory. Any advise?

If it helps, I'm running Arch Linux with Apache HTTPD 2.2 and PHP 5.3.8. Thank you!

EDIT:
I forgot to mention some extra information. Since I'm working on this website with another person, we each have "local" copies of this website in our user directories. (I say local, but it's really our user directories on the same server which is hosting the public version of this website). Apache is set up to allow user directories (http://thisismytestwebsite.com/~myusername), which is how we view our "local" copies. When I go to click on the login link, the page loads up fine. Everything that we have is backed up using Git, and everything that we have is synchronized properly (we just checked).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file you're trying to open exists, and that the path is an *absolute* path.

It's fairly easy to generate a relative path from one file to another:

```
 dirname(__FILE__) . "/../include.php";
```

Will include the file 'include.php' from one folder up from where the current file is.

`__FILE__` is a magic PHP constant, use it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the apache process is blocked from reading the `index.php` file due to file system permissions.

Try to adjust permissions (`chmod`) and ownership (`chown`) of the file according to your working `index.html`

Comment: I'm not sure that that's the case. I have everything set to the same file permissions (chmod 755) as index.html. Thank you for your answer, however.